# Is there any other steganography algorithm other than LSB?

Tags: steganography

LSB is most commonly used in steganography. Which algorithm can be used instead of LSB?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. Did you check Wikipedia?

Answer (score 1):

Any data that is not (that) significant to the protocol can be used for steganography. LSB just depends on the least significant bits as they are not significant *for RGB coded pictures*. I'd not even call it a steganographic technique, it's just about determining what data can possibly be used for it.

Comment: Converted from a comment that was being upvoted. Either we should close the question or we should answer them.